# Why does oot say "hey" in usleep -o?

Tags: centos, timeout

On a Centos 6.6 box I noticed this...

```
[root@abcd /]# usleep --help
Usage: usleep [microseconds]
  -v, --version     Display the version of this program, and exit
  -o, --oot         oot says hey!

Help options:
  -?, --help        Show this help message
  --usage           Display brief usage message
[root@abcd /]# usleep -o
oot says hey!
```

While the man page doesn't mention it...

```
OPTIONS
   --usage Show short usage message.

   --help, -?
          Print help information.

   -v, --version
          Print version information.
```

So, why does oot say "`hey`"?

**Edit:**  Certainly this is an Easter egg, but it seems like it might be one with a story.

Comment: Why does apt-get say moo?

Comment: Devs don't know either https://www.mail-archive.com/pld-cvs-commit@lists.pld-linux.org/msg117735.html

Comment: "Oot" can be an acronym for "out of time" which makes some sense in this context.

Answer (score 9):

Not sure about the easter egg, but

> Why does oot say “hey” in usleep -o?

simple, because it's in the [source](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-oe/blob/master/meta-oe/recipes-core/usleep/files/usleep.c):

```
struct poptOption options[] = {
        { "version", 'v', POPT_ARG_NONE, &showVersion, 0, 
        "Display the version of this program, and exit" },
        { "oot", 'o', POPT_ARG_NONE, &showOot, 0, 
        "oot says hey!" },
    POPT_AUTOHELP
        { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 }
    };
```

There is no further indication on why it was introduced. *ducks*.